# Laravel Record Update - Softdeletes record when updating the record

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, sql-update

I have a basic CRUD of *services*. I've added the SoftDeletes in the model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Service extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'services';
    protected $fillable = [
          'name','description',
    ];
}
```

When updating the record, I'm using the Laravel Eloquent, here is the code:

```
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
                            'name' => 'required',
                        ]);

        $service = Service::find($request->id);

        $service->name = $request->name;
        $service->description = $request->description;
        $service->save();
     }
```

Route in *web.php* is:

```
Route::post('service/update', 'ServiceController@update')
            ->name('updateService');
```

I don't know why this happens but every time I try to update a record, the `deleted_at` column is also updated (it is populated with the timestamp). What I want is that, the record will be updated not deleted.

PS

I've also tried it in other models that has `SoftDeletes` and the problem also occurs, the record is updated and then deleted.

Comment: Can you show us your migration please? If you're not using migrations, make sure the deleted at doesn't have a default.

Comment: Can you log the executed queries?

Comment: Hi @Bryan, 
I am not using migrations at the moment since there are records that was still not placed in seeder.

I directly added the column in the [table](http://shorturl.at/tuvDI). 

Thanks for asking in regards with the `default`. While exploring the table, I found out that `On Update Current_Timestamp` was checked which means that every time there is a record update, the `deleted_at` column will be populated.

Unchecking the `On Update Current_Timestamp` solves the issue.

Comment: Awesome, glad it was an easy fix.